# cannot create surface even though it seems correct

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

```py
self.image = pygame.Surface(
                int(math.sqrt((end_pos[1] - start_pos[1])**2 +(end_pos[0] - start_pos[0])**2)),  width)
```

returns the error:

> ```
> ValueError: size needs to be (int width, int height)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to the constructor of [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is a tuple with the size of the *Surface* (`pygame.Surface((with, height))`):

<s>`self.image = pygame.Surface(int(math.sqrt((end_pos[1] - start_pos[1])**2 +(end_pos[0] - start_pos[0])**2)),  width)`</s>

```py
self.image = pygame.Surface(
    (int(math.sqrt((end_pos[1] - start_pos[1])**2 +(end_pos[0] - start_pos[0])**2)),  width))
```

respectively

```py
value = int(math.sqrt((end_pos[1] - start_pos[1])**2 +(end_pos[0] - start_pos[0])**2))
self.image = pygame.Surface((value, width))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, how could I have been so stupid